# Sub selecting a dynamic number of rows as columns in a single query

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Hey guys I have the following 3 tables:

```
      person                    event                       attendance
| id | name | age | | id |   name  |    added   | | id | pId | eId | attended |
|-----------------| |---------------------------| |---------------------------|
| 5  | bob  | 20  | | 0  | wedding | 01.01.2013 | | 0  |  5  |  0  |   YES    |
| 6  | ryan | 25  | | 1  |  party  | 01.01.2013 | | 1  |  5  |  1  |   NO     |
```

So "person" and "attendance" are growing dynamically and "event" is a static table to hold the event names. I am trying to achieve the following result:

```
| id | name | age | wedding | party |
|-----------------------------------|
| 0  | bob  | 20  |   YES   |  NO   |
| 1  | ryan | 25  |   NO    |  NO   |
```

I should propably mention that my live database is quite big (I have like 11 static event names, so this example would end up with 14 columns) and there is also another table (simulating flags) in between so performance is quite important.
I wonder if this is even possible with one single query and how to exactly achieve it?

Comment: sounds like you need a join statement in your query

Comment: joins would help me combine columns but in this case i need rows (results of the event table) to be my columns

Comment: make two queries, one to get the names of all events, then build your second query in php or whatever. if you absolutely need to do it all in the database you can write a stored procedure and use mysqls limited string handling methods to concat together a query and fire that as a prepared statement. ` SET @stmt_text = CONCAT("create temporary table tempTabDynamic as select * FROM ", iParameter);
 PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_text;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.age, 
  MAX(IF(e.name='wedding', a.attended, NULL)) AS `wedding`,
  MAX(IF(e.name='party', a.attended, NULL)) AS `party`
FROM person p
JOIN attendance a ON a.pId = p.id
JOIN event e ON a.eId = e.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

You need the list of event names before you can write this query.

---

Re your comment, I see what you mean, there are *no* rows for ryan attending any event, so that person doesn't show up in the result.  The `JOIN` only returns person rows that have one or more matching attendance rows.

The way to solve this is with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  That returns the person row whether there are matching rows or not.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.age,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(e.name='wedding', a.attended, NULL)), 'NO')AS `wedding`,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(e.name='party', a.attended, NULL)), 'NO') AS `party`
FROM person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance a ON a.pId = p.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN event e ON a.eId = e.id
GROUP BY p.id;

+----+------+------+---------+-------+
| id | name | age  | wedding | party |
+----+------+------+---------+-------+
|  5 | bob  |   20 | YES     | NO    |
|  6 | ryan |   25 | NO      | NO    |
+----+------+------+---------+-------+
```

PS: Shouldn't the `id` column in your sample result have values 5 and 6?

Comment: In your question, you show only one attendance row per person per event.  It's not clear what other case you want to handle.  Can you edit your question and provide an example?

Comment: well using max kind of returns only 1 result. ryan from the example is missing.

Comment: GROUP BY queries return one row per distinct value of the named column.  Then MAX() or other aggregate functions are limited to the set of rows in each respective group.

Comment: this is absolutely what i was looking for! thank you very much.